# Kafka server cannot start in shell script

Tags: shell, apache-kafka, centos8

I'm trying to start kafka in a centos8 cluster using this below shell scripts(like `kfk start`) but with no success. By executing single command  `kafka-server-start.sh -daemon $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties` I can successfully start the kafka in seperate machines but when using `xcall` below, the kafka service just never starts, neither adds to the log. I am wondering why this happens, maybe there's something missing in the shell script, any ideas?
**The kfk shell is like thi**s:

```
#!/bin/bash
if(($#!=1))
then
        echo please input start or stop！
        exit;
fi

if [ $1 = start ]
then
        xcall kafka-server-start.sh -daemon $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties
elif [ $1 = stop ]
then echo input command is xcall kafka-server-stop.sh && xcall kafka-server-stop.sh
else
        echo please input start or stop!
fi
```

**In which the **xcall** is like this:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#1 get parameter count

pcount=$#
if((pcount==0)); then
echo no args;
exit;
fi

#2 get command
cmd=$*
echo command is $*

#3 loop
for((host=102; host<105; host++)); do
        echo --------------------------------- hadoop$host -------------------------
        ssh -tt user@hadoop$host "$cmd"
done
```

-------------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------
After trial and error, I found out if I remove the `-t` after `ssh` in the xcall script, the command can work as expected. So the command should be:
 `ssh user@hadoop$host "$cmd"`

From my understanding, `-t` just forces the pseudo-terminal, I don't quite understand how this will impact the command after ssh. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what xcall is, but I would use Ansible if you're trying to start all brokers at once

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the suggestion, but I am learning the most basic way to manage clusters and I am stuck at this. The second script above is the xcall script

Comment: The most basic approach is to not use xcall at all... Can you explain why you think you need it or want to use it?

Comment: Systemctl wrappers would be better than this `kfk` script, then you can just use `systemctl start/stop kafka` similar to other OS services https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-kafka-centos-8/

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks I will definitely take some time dig into `systemctl`. BTW, I've found the solution, but I don't understand why, do you have any ideas?

Comment: You're just issuing a command to a remote host, so you don't need to allocate a TTY